# BIOS doesn't recognize USB

Tags: windows-8, usb, bios, windows-installation

My Mom recently bought an ASUS VivoBook X202E laptop.  I have a USB (bootable) with Windows 8.1 on it, which I'm trying to install on her laptop.  When I go into the BIOS of the laptop to change the boot order, so I can launch the USB, there is no other recognized devices besides the hard drive.  When I try the USB on my own laptop, the BIOS recognizes the USB and I can use it properly.  I haven't updated the BIOS on my Mom's laptop, but do you really think the BIOS needs to be updated if the laptop is < 2 years old?

```
Windows 8 x64
Intel® Core™ i3 Processor
Integrated Intel® HD Graphics
```

Comment: What is the motherboard?

Comment: You likely have to disable Secure Boot and enable the "Launch CSM" option in the BIOS for legacy boot support, unless you made your thumbdrive UEFI/GPT

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I don't know.  I tried looking at the manufacturer site and other sites, but could not find the model name.  I know ASUS makes their own motherboards, so it's an ASUSTeK motherboard.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if the the thumbdrive you created is probably not a UEFI/GPT thumbdrive, but a BIOS/MBR thumbdrive.  To boot off this, you need to enable legacy or CSM (Compatibility Support Module) boot.  While I don't know your specific mother board, this generally entails:

1. Disabling Secure Boot
2. Enabling "Launch CSM" or similar, or some "Legacy Boot" support